# 'range(of:in:for:)' is unavailable: use range(of:in:for:) instead

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I don't know where is wrong in code :
But error said not available my code :
Help me please :

```
/// Swift4
///'range(of:in:for:)' is unavailable: use range(of:in:for:) instead
let weeks = NSCalendar.current.range(of: NSCalendar.Unit.weekOfMonth, in: NSCalendar.Unit.month, for: anotherClass() as Date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `NSCalendar` in Swift 3+. Use the native struct `Calendar`.

And omit `NSCalendar.Unit`. The compiler can infer the type

```
let weeks = Calendar.current.range(of: .weekOfMonth, in: .month, for: Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two `range(of:in:for)` in `NSCalendar`.

One is `range(of: NSCalendar.Unit, in: NSCalendar.Unit, for: Date)`.
Another is `range(of: Calendar.Component, in: Calendar.Component, for: Date)`.

And the first is not available in Swift 4. You need to use the second. Unfortunately, the convention of Swift omits type names in the method signature...

Try this:

```
let weeks = Calendar.current.range(of: Calendar.Component.weekOfMonth, in: Calendar.Component.month, for: anotherClass() as Date)
```

(If your `anotherClass()` returns `NSDate`, you should better update it to return `Date`.)

---

The result type of `range(of: Calendar.Component, in: Calendar.Component, for: Date)` is `Range<Int>?` and not `NSRange`. You may need to modify the codes using `weeks`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar`

Answer (score 0):

Try Calender class because NSCalender is not appropriate for swift versions.